# init pytorch model : cuda out of memory ,GPU memory is enough

Tags: python, docker, deep-learning, pytorch

envs: ubuntu20.04 a RTX3090x4 docker container
I use vscode launch.json to debug the code of a pytorch model, setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0, it indicated this:
`RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect. For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.`
However, the nvidia-smi command indicate that all the GPUs' status are zero. when i set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 the code runs normally.

i try to use other gpus, it runs normally, i just can not use gpu0, i delete the container and rebuild a new one, this problem still exist.

Comment: can you run `nvidia-smi` and check the GPU usage?

Comment: I have run the nvidia-smi already, all the gpus are free,  
GPU memory is totally sufficient. it's really wired that i can run the same code if i don't use the specific gpu. i'm sure my code are fine. So i reboot the server . and problem solved,  maybe it is a gpu driver problem because  if the memory is insufficient it will have an error like '' cuda out of memory,trying to allocate  xxx Mib..."  not like i mentioned before.